# How to keep same slide state in Nested LazyColumn?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, jetpack

[image]

A `LazyColumn` includes another `LazyColumn`, and the second `LazyColumn` includes a `HorizontalPager`. Each pager include a list.

How to solve this issue, or does anyone have another idea better to implement the function? I provided a gif about the sample.

Problem: I would like to make the entire layout slide together by sliding the LazyColumn below. However, in my implementation, only the LazyColumn below slides and cannot make the entire page slide upwards as it slides

```
@Composable
fun RadioStationPage(viewModel: RadioStationViewModel = hiltViewModel()){
   ...
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ){
        ...
                  item { ProgramRankPager( ... )}
    }
}
@Composable
private fun ProgramRankPager(
   ...
){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier .fillMaxWidth()
.heightIn(max = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp)
    ) {
        TabRow(
           ...
        ) {
             tabs.forEachIndexed { index, rankTab ->
               ...
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(
            count = pagers.size,
            state = pageState,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)

        ) {
            //include three page,Simplified into one
            ProgramRankList(...)
            SecondPage()
            ThirdPage()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ProgramRankList(...){
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()//...
    ){
        ...
        items(items = programStatus){ item->
            item?.let { bean->
                ProgramRankListItem(
                   ...
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't quite tell from the GIF what the issue is. Can you edit your question to clarify what the exact problem is with your current solution?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to make the entire layout slide together by sliding the LazyColumn below. However, in my implementation, only the LazyColumn below slides and cannot make the entire page slide upwards as it slides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one has answered yet, I'll give it a shot.

I think there is a conceptual design flaw in what you are trying to achieve. Let me point out some things that I consider to be difficult:

- You have two scrollable `LazyColumn`s where one is a child of the other. In Jetpack Compose, this only is possible if the nested `LazyColumn` has a fixed height. In your case, this seems to be okay as you set a height to the parent of the nested `LazyColumn` by setting `Modifier.weight(1f)` to the `HorizontalPager`, and then just fill that height in your nested `LazyColumn`.
- However, using this `Modifier.weight(1f)` does not really make sense on a child of another `LazyColumn`. It will probably do nothing, or it will push all other content off screen, or it may lead to unpredictable behavior.
- If you combine two `LazyColumns` and have the inner one with fixed size, you can only scroll the inner one by scrolling with your finger exactly on top of it. If you want to scroll the outer LazyColumn, you have to scroll in an area outside of the inner LazyColumn.

To sum this up, if you want to make the outer `LazyColumn` scroll by swiping on the inner `LazyColumn`, then you have to make the inner `LazyColumn` non-scrollable. You can disable scrolling on the nested `LazyColumn` with the following code:

```
@Composable
fun ProgramRankList(...){
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        userScrollEnabled = false,  // disable scrolling
        //...
    ){
        //...
    }
}
```

Then, only the outer `LazyColumn` will consume the scroll event, and will make the whole page scroll.

However, I feel like you should rethink your UI design or explain more clearly what exact scrolling behavior you want to achieve, in case I did not understand properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I try this way,It solve the slide question,But I take the Paging3 Library to solve paging,So It doesn't working when I set the inner LazyColumn non-scrollable.Thank you again for your reply,I am intend to alter My UI design.